# KineticJS which layer clicked?

Tags: javascript, html, kineticjs

I use KineticJS add images to layers. I need to know which layer clicked.

This is jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/yvp79ryf/1/

If i clicked first image just need get alert clicked is first layers otherwise second layer

HTML

```
<div id="container"></div>
<script src="http://d3lp1msu2r81bx.cloudfront.net/kjs/js/lib/kinetic-v4.4.3.min.js"></script>
<script defer="defer">
```

JavaScript

```
  var stage = new Kinetic.Stage({
    container: 'container',
    width: 578,
    height: 200
  });


  var layer = new Kinetic.Layer();
  var imageObj = new Image();
  imageObj.onload = function() {
  var yoda = new Kinetic.Image({
      x: 140,
      y: stage.getHeight() / 2 - 59,
      image: imageObj,
      width: 106,
      height: 118
    });

    layer.add(yoda);
    stage.add(layer);

  };
  imageObj.src = 'http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/demos/assets/yoda.jpg';



  var layer2 = new Kinetic.Layer();
  var imageObj2 = new Image();
  imageObj2.onload = function() {
  var filteredYoda = new Kinetic.Image({
      x: 280,
      y: stage.getHeight() / 2 - 59,
      image: imageObj2,
      width: 106,
      height: 118
    });

    layer2.add(filteredYoda);
    stage.add(layer2);
  };
  imageObj2.src = 'http://demo-stable-ofbiz.apache.org/images/products/GZ-1000/small.png';
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set id to layers to identify them.

```
var layer = new Kinetic.Layer({id:1});
var layer2 = new Kinetic.Layer({id:2});
```

Add click event handler on stage

```
stage.on('click', function(e) {
    if(e.targetNode.parent.attrs.id == 1){
        alert('first layer');
    }else{
        alert('second layer');
    }
});
```

You can check layer id through the descendants

`e` is MouseEvent object.

`e.targetNode` is Kinetic.Image

`e.targetNode.parent` is Kinetic.Layer

`e.targetNode.parent.attrs.id` is id of Kinetic.Layer

Answer (score 1):

If you click on an image, you can use `.getLayer()` to get a reference to the layer that your clicked image is on.

```
stage.on('click', function(e) {
    console.log('layer:',e.target.getLayer().id());
});
```

KineticJS does not listen for clicks on the empty part of a layer.  Therefore, if you click on an empty part of the stage then you cannot tell which layer was clicked. But since since `layer2` is above `layer` then if you click on the empty part of the stage then you're always clicking on the top layer (layer2).